# Python in-list replacement

Tags: python

Intent: In a collection of variables, if any variable happens to be a string, then split on ";" and make it a list. I have tried with the following code but its not working.

I was expecting l2 to be ["3", "4"] but instead it still is "3;4"

Please have a look at it and **kindly explain how to loop over the list variables and replace them in place**:

```
>>> l1 = ["1" ,"2"]
>>> l2 = "3;4"
>>> l3 = ["5", "6"]
>>>
>>> for x in [l1, l2, l3]:
    print("Working on: {}".format(x))
    if isinstance(x, basestring):
        x = x.split(";")
        print("New x: {}".format(x))
    else:
        print("Its same")


Working on: ['1', '2']
Its same
Working on: 3;4
New x: ['3', '4']
Working on: ['5', '6']
Its same
>>> l1, l2, l3
(['1', '2'], '3;4', ['5', '6'])
```

**Expected values:**

```
>>> l1, l2, l3
(['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Python are immutable - they cannot be changed in-place. Therefore:

```
x = x.split(";")
```

Creates *a new object* (a `list`) and assigns it to the name `x`, but *doesn't* change the list being iterated over. In this case, though, *even if you change the list*, `l2` still references the original `str` object.

In Python names are references to objects - `[l1, l2, l3]` just means a list whose first index references the object currently referenced by the name `l1`, and so on.

You could make this a function instead:

```
def splitter(x):
    print("Working on: {}".format(x))
    if isinstance(x, basestring):
        x = x.split(";")
        print("New x: {}".format(x))
    else:
        print("It's the same")
    return x
```

Then you can do:

```
l1 = splitter(l1)
l2 = splitter(l2)
l3 = splitter(l3)
```

and get the result you want.

Alternatively, unpack the list back to the names (here using a list comprehension):

```
l1, l2, l3 = [splitter(x) for x in [l1, l2, l3]]
```

(or, the long way round)

```
vals = [l1, l2, l3] # create list
for i, x in enumerate(vals): # iterate through list
    vals[i] = splitter(x) # modify list
l1, l2, l3 = vals # unpack list
```

Comment: "Creates a new str object and assigns it to the name x" -- `x.split()` returns a list, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you work with `for x in lists:`, `x` is a copy of the list item and when you assign the list back to `x` you are assigning it to the `x` and not the original list. Instead, you can do:

```
l1,l2,l3 = [i.split(';') if isinstance(i, basestring) else i for i in [l1,l2,l3]]

>>> print l1, l2, l3
['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']
```

Comment: No, `x` is not a copy of the list item.  It *is* the list item.